# Transparent background pictureBox over another one

Tags: c#, winforms

I got stuck on that situation; I have a panel that contains 2 pictureBoxes.

*BackColor*s of the *pictureBox*es are transparent; and neither *panel*'s nor *window*'s *BackColor* is transparent but when I execute the program, it looks like that.

[img link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tpwk.jpg)

I will be appreciated if anyone enlighten me about what I am missing!

Thank you.

Comment: can you provide a bit of source code?

Comment: Now, I see the point. It is about a parent-child relation between pictureBoxes. I solved my problem. Thank you :)